# Hide Price and Replace with button

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I have created one module for hide price and replace button, with add to cart in product view page,

[image]

For this module I created 4 files:

- `system.xml`
- `adminhtml.xml`
- `config.xml`
- `data.php`

but, where to write logic for the hide price, I don't understand.

Any tips on how to get that working? 
    Thanks! pls, help me..

This is my `addtocart.phtml` file. in this file i have used the condition user logged or not and **if user not logged then price not display**.

But how can set condition if **user also logged in but price not display**.

```
<?php
    //condition to check user is loggedin or not
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() AND Mage::getStoreConfig('sigma1_product/sigma1_group/price_enable')):
    echo '<span class="login_for_price"><b>'.Mage::getStoreConfig('sigma1_product/sigma1_group/cart_text').'</b></span><br>';
    return;
    endif;
?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <div class="add-to-cart">
                <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
                    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, it may help you.

If you only want to hide price then:

Open **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/** folder and copy price.phtml file to the app/design/frontend/base/template/themeXXX/catalog/product/ folder, where XXX is the number of your theme, and then place the following code on top of it:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_price"><strong>Login to See Price (you can show your text by getting from config field)</strong>    </span><br>';
return;
}
?>
```

If you want to hide add to cart button from product detail:

**app/design/frontend/default/themeXXX/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml file.** Add the following code on top of it:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_details" style="float:left"><strong>Login to     Add to Cart</strong></span>';
return;
}
?>
```

Comment: this code can I use with my custom module? as i said above ? u can see my image as i uploaded.

Comment: I think you can use this code along with the isLoggedIn() condition, you can use your modules fields also like if its enabled then only it will work. You can also get your config fields value like Message to show custom message

Comment: i have used the condition user logged or not and if user not logged then price not display.

But how can set condition if user also logged in but price not display. in this current file

Comment: so you don't want to show price for both logged and non logged in user right?

Comment: yes i don't want to show price for both logged and non logged in user

Comment: Then I think you just need to modify
`if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()).`

So to achieve this you can create new config field in your module i.e **Show Price: Yes/No**

And in If condition just check  something like this:

`<?php
if(Show Price== 'Yes'){
echo '<span class="login_for_details" style="float:left"><strong>Login to     Add to Cart</strong></span>';
return;
}
?>`

Comment: yes u r right, i just removed the user login condition it works both logged or non logged user

Comment: Okay, Grt. If you achieved what you were looking for then please vote for this. Thanks :)